# Problem with german umlauts in csv file when i write from php

Tags: php, html, csv

Greeting

I have a problem when I want to use the php script to enter data from the database into the csv file. It prints everything right in the database, but when it prints to the csv file, then it comes to a character error, i.e. does not print them well.
Examples of errors Ã¶, Ã¤, Ã¼ ... and what I need ä, ö, ü ....

If I can print somehow to the csv file the way it is in the database?
My code:

```
<?php 



require_once 'connections.php'; 


$query = "SELECT Artikelnummer_im_Shop, EAN_GTIN_Barcodenummer_UPC, 
 Herstellerartikelnummern_HAN_MPN, Hersteller_Markenname, 
 Produktname,Preis_Brutto, Lieferzeit, Produktbeschreibung, ProduktURL, 
 BildURL_1, Versandkosten, Vorkasse, Paydirekt, Paypal, 
 Kreditkartenzahlung_uber_BS_PAYONE_GmbH, Versandkosten_Kommentar 
FROM app_table";

$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query) or die("database error:". 
mysqli_error($connect));

$file   = "inko-table.csv";
// Delete file if exist
unlink($file);
// Write to the file or create if not exist
$f      = fopen($file, 'w'); // Open in write mode ('w' will overwrite everything everytime)

$table      = "app_table";
$sql        = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM $table");
$num_rows   = mysqli_num_rows($sql);
$products   = mysqli_fetch_array($sql);
// Writing data in file var $file

$i = 1;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {

  $nameComma                  = $row['Produktname'];
    $name                       = str_replace(",", "", $nameComma);
    $pzn                        = $row['EAN_GTIN_Barcodenummer_UPC'];
    $url                        = $row['ProduktURL'];
    $brand                      = $row['Hersteller_Markenname'];
  $priceComma                 = $row['Preis_Brutto'];
    $price                      = str_replace(",", ".", $priceComma);
    $Artikelnummer              = $row['Artikelnummer_im_Shop'];
  $ProduktbeschreibungComma   = $row['Produktbeschreibung'];
    $Produktbeschreibung        = str_replace(",", "", $ProduktbeschreibungComma);
    $Herstellerartikelnummern   = $row['Herstellerartikelnummern_HAN_MPN'];
  $LieferzeitComma            = $row['Lieferzeit'];
    $Lieferzeit                 = str_replace(",", "", $LieferzeitComma);
    $BildURL_1                  = $row['BildURL_1'];
  $VersandkostenComma         = $row['Versandkosten'];
    $Versandkosten              = str_replace(",", ".", $VersandkostenComma);
    $Vorkasse                   = $row['Vorkasse'];
    $Paydirekt                  = $row['Paydirekt'];
    $Paypal                     = $row['Paypal'];
    $Kreditkartenzahlung        = $row['Kreditkartenzahlung_uber_BS_PAYONE_GmbH'];
  $KommentarComma             = $row['Versandkosten_Kommentar'];
    $Kommentar                  = str_replace(",", "", $KommentarComma);


    if ($i==1) {
        $product = "Artikelnummer im Shop".","."EAN / GTIN / Barcodenummer / UPC".","."Herstellerartikelnummern (HAN/MPN)".","."Hersteller / Markenname".","."Produktname".","."Preis (Brutto)".","."Lieferzeit".","."Produktbeschreibung".","."ProduktURL".","."BildURL_1".","."Versandkosten".","."Vorkasse".","."Paydirekt".","."Paypal".","."Kreditkartenzahlung über BS PAYONE GmbH".","."Versandkosten Kommentar"."\n".$Artikelnummer.",".$pzn.",".$Herstellerartikelnummern.",".$brand.",".$name.",".$price.",".$Lieferzeit.",".$Produktbeschreibung.",".$url.",".$BildURL_1.",".$Versandkosten.",".$Vorkasse.",".$Paydirekt.",".$Paypal.",".$Kreditkartenzahlung.",".$Kommentar."\n";
    } else {
        $product = $Artikelnummer.",".$pzn.",".$Herstellerartikelnummern.",".$brand.",".$name.",".$price.",".$Lieferzeit.",".$Produktbeschreibung.",".$url.",".$BildURL_1.",".$Versandkosten.",".$Vorkasse.",".$Paydirekt.",".$Paypal.",".$Kreditkartenzahlung.",".$Kommentar."\n";
    }

    $i++;

    fwrite($f, $product);
}
fclose($f);
```

?>

Comment: You should not manually construct csv, instead you should use `fputcsv()`.

Comment: It's almost certainly a character-encoding issue.  Make sure everything is UTF8 (the input, the output, the DB, the PHP script itself...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
string utf8_decode ( string $data );
```

for example:

```
$ProduktbeschreibungComma   = utf8_decode ($row['Produktbeschreibung']);
```

It should return the correct umlauts.

If it is in your csv file. Use utf_decode before output. Try to change the file_encoding of the csv file to utf8.